# Changing Django's default list of Common Password

Tags: python, django

I just try to use Django. when i try to create superuser with the createsuperuser and i try to use some common password like abcd1234 (because abc or 123 isn't allowed), it cannot accept it because apparently that my password is too common, i know that the createsuperuser use somekind of password list to match mine with theirs. I want to ask that whether it is possible to change the password list.

i already tried to open manage.py to find the createsuperuser method but i didnt find it because it only contains run(sys.argv)

Comment: The relevant code is not in the createsuperuser command, but in the [password validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.password_validation).

Comment: You can find the `createsuperuser` source code here https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py but the validation happens here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/d232fd76a85870daf345fd8f8d617fe7802ae194/django/contrib/auth/password_validation.py#L35

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to.

Look for a folder which follows the path:

`\Python3\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth` or the equivalent on your system.

In it, you should see a file named `common-passwords.txt.gz`.

Inside it, there will be a file called `common-passwords.new.txt`

You should just be able to change the passwords on the list. One password per line. Passwords should be entirely lowercase as Django automatically translates passwords to lowercase for comparison against the common password list.

Relevant documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

You can follow the other answer as well. But you will have to place your password file whenever you change your `virtualenv`. Here is the way to keep it in the project.

1. Place your file in project folder where `manage.py` exists
2. Open `settings.py` from your projects folder and add the following

   ```
    FILE_NAME = "custom_common_password_list.txt"
   ```
3. Create a file `custom_common_password.py` under projects folder

   ```
   # projectname/custom_common_password.py

   import os
   from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import CommonPasswordValidator
   from django.conf import settings


   class CustomCommonPasswordValidator(CommonPasswordValidator):
       def __init__(self):
           super().__init__(password_list_path=os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, settings.FILE_NAME))
   ```

We are basically calling the [CommonPasswordValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/contrib/auth/password_validation/#CommonPasswordValidator) with our file path.

4. Modify the `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS` and add the following:

   ```
   AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
       # ...
       {
           'NAME': 'projectname.custom_common_password.CustomCommonPasswordValidator',
       },
       #...
   ]
   ```

We comment the existing `CommonPasswordValidator` and place our custom validator. Make sure to replace `projectname` with your project name.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend using a safer password.

Why? You don't want hackers to guess your password and hijack your website. Even small websites are targets of large fishing attempts and can be used to spread malware and do bad stuff.

One method that hackers use to gain entrance to your system is by using common password lists. So make sure that you choose a password that is not in such lists.

An easy to remember password which is still safe might consist of several words. As an alternative, you could use a password manager to remember a random string of characters for you.

You can find more suggestions here on how to create safe passwords: https://www.bu.edu/tech/support/information-security/security-for-everyone/how-to-choose-a-strong-password/